# ubuntu login loop after install nvidia-375 graphic driver

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, ubuntu-16.04, gnome

i ran into the login loop issue. I've tried several solutions such as check .Xauthority files, start lightdm service and so on. But the issues remains there. I checked .xsession-errors file it gives me following logs

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (3220) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (3213) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (3072) killed by TERM signal
```

Dose anyone has an idea about what happened to my machine?
BTW: my graphic card is geforce titan x
Thx

Answer (score 1):

I have geforce GTX 1080 ti, tried to install NVIDIA 410 drivers. Ran into both blackscreen and login loops on ubuntu 16.04.

I entered terminal with Alt+ctrl+F1, purged nvidia* and sudo rebooted. Now your computer will run on noveau drivers.

After that I directly installed the cuda 9.0 toolkit from nvidia website (the .deb file is safer), which installed its dependencies (NVIDIA drivers). The drivers will automatically be set to the ones installed by cuda (for me it installed 384). you can check this in Ubuntu 16.04 in Additional drivers GUI.

The login loop didn't appear again.

Answer (score 0):

The new [systemd](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd) in this case can help you:

1. download the nvidia driver (**NVIDIA*.run** file)
2. enter in terminal mode `ctrl+alt+F1` and login
3. switch the target to systemd target **multi-user.target** with this command: `systemctl isolate multi-user.target` which corresponds to **runlevel 3**
4. run the driver with `sudo ./NVIDIA*.run`
5. Reboot the system with `reboot`

Enjoy